# When a user select one or more from the combo box , the check box must be checked automatically

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have a check box and a combo box on my form, and I am trying to resolve this question, **How can I do this on Flex 3**? Thank you :)

Comment: It is unclear what you try to do? Atleast post some code which you have tried or possible then screen shot.

Comment: I have a combo box and a check box on my form, I want that  the check box to be checked automatically when I select something on the combo box.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple. Check following code:

```
<s:DropDownList labelField="value" change="onchangeHandler(event)">
</s:DropDownList>

<s:CheckBox id="testChk" />
```

On DropDown change change handler select checkbox

```
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
       protected function onchangeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
       {
            testChk.selected = true;
       }    
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Hope it helps.